# How to display image from NSFileManager Url in swift

Tags: image, swift

How can I display an image in an `UIImageView` from

```
documentsDirectoryURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("img"))
```

For example, something like this

```
imageView.image = UIImage(documentsDirectoryURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("img")))
```

This is my documentDirectoryURL

`let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("img")).path)
```

Good luck